# addcustomtag doesn't work on joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla2.5, meta

On one of my pages on website, I noticed some meta properties for Facebook (og properties)

However, I want to change them to another og properties.... but the page is dynamic and for different users shows different content, I wanted to insert metas right in php code which generates the page content.

I tried to use

```
JFactory::getDocument()->addCustomTag('<meta property="og:type" content="articles" />');
```

But no reaction... old meta roperty og:type didn't change.

Please, suggest some way to edit page metas or way to use addCustomTag correctly.

Thanks

Comment: By default joomla doesn't add open graph meta tags. You have to check your template or 3rd party plugins that may have added them.

Comment: Yes, those meta tags seem to come with some plugin... however, is there a way how to override them from the php file?

Answer (score 0):

Joomla doesn't add open graph meta tags by default. You have to find the 3rd party plugin or the template setting that creates them and disable it.

You could place then the new og tags using [JDocumentHTML/addCustomTag](http://docs.joomla.org/JDocumentHTML/addCustomTag) function. Here is an example:

```
$doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addCustomTag( '
    <meta property="og:title" content="" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="" />
    ' );
```

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: Ok, I will try this and let you know the results.

Comment: This works.. but I didn't want to block third party metas.. I used different solution

Comment: Ok so is your problem sorted?

Answer (score 0):

I have JFB Connect extension installed, so I just used {SCOpenGraph image=PATH} JFB shortcode to change the old metas.